Building microchip-ung/mepa C library gives error related to timercmp call syntax
Cross-compiling the microchip-ung/mepa library to ARM, using xilinx 2016.4 SDK (trying C11 flag) is leading to the following error:
/home/mesa/mesa-v2024.06-1/mepa/common/include/mepa_os_linux.h:58:123: error: expected expression before '>' token
#define MEPA_MTIMER_TIMEOUT(timer) (gettimeofday(&((timer)->now),NULL)==0 && timercmp(&((timer)->now),&((timer)->timeout),>)) /**< Timer timeout */

Is this an issue with C version? i.e. is passing the '>' operator in the call
(timercmp(&((timer)->now),&((timer)->timeout),>)) not legal in earlier C versions?
Other things it could be (?)

a missing compiler flag
incomplete target environment specified to cmake?

Thanks
UPDATE: adding header file containing the macro definition:
    // Copyright (c) 2004-2020 Microchip Technology Inc. and its subsidiaries.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

#ifndef _MEPA_OS_LINUX_H_
#define _MEPA_OS_LINUX_H_

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

typedef int8_t    i8;
typedef int16_t   i16;
typedef int32_t   i32;
typedef int64_t   i64;

typedef uint8_t   u8;
typedef uint16_t  u16;
typedef uint32_t  u32;
typedef uint64_t  u64;

typedef uint8_t   BOOL;

#define MEPA_DIV64(dividend, divisor) ((dividend) / (divisor))
#define MEPA_MOD64(dividend, divisor) ((dividend) % (divisor))

#define MEPA_LABS(arg)                labs(arg)

typedef struct {
    struct timeval timeout;   /**< Timeout */
    struct timeval now;       /**< Time right now */
} mepa_mtimer_t;

#define MEPA_NSLEEP(nsec) {                                     \
    struct timespec ts;                                         \
    ts.tv_sec = 0;                                              \
    ts.tv_nsec = nsec;                                          \
    while(nanosleep(&ts, &ts) == -1 && errno == EINTR) {        \
    }                                                           \
}

/** Sleep for \param msec milliseconds */
#define MEPA_MSLEEP(msec) {                                     \
    struct timespec ts;                                         \
    ts.tv_sec = msec / 1000;                                    \
    ts.tv_nsec = (msec % 1000) * 1000000;                       \
    while(nanosleep(&ts, &ts) == -1 && errno == EINTR) {        \
    }                                                           \
}

#define MEPA_MTIMER_START(timer,msec) { \
    (void) gettimeofday(&((timer)->timeout),NULL);   \
    (timer)->timeout.tv_usec+=msec*1000; \
    if ((timer)->timeout.tv_usec>=1000000) { (timer)->timeout.tv_sec+=(timer)->timeout.tv_usec/1000000; (timer)->timeout.tv_usec%=1000000; } \
} /**< Start timer */

#define MEPA_MTIMER_TIMEOUT(timer) (gettimeofday(&((timer)->now),NULL)==0 && timercmp(&((timer)->now),&((timer)->timeout),>)) /**< Timer timeout */

#define MEPA_MTIMER_CANCEL(timer) /**< No action in this implementation. */

static inline time_t MEPA_UPTIME_SECONDS(void)
{
    struct timespec time;
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time) == 0) {
        return time.tv_sec;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

#define MEPA_LLABS(arg)               llabs(arg)
#define MEPA_ABS(arg)                 abs(arg)


#endif /* _MEPA_OS_LINUX_H_ */


@pmacfarlane Thanks; please see update to OP, in which I include the header file containing the macro definition with the syntax. Thanks

I've deleted my comment. From the manpage, turns out timercmp() is actually a macro, so that syntax is probably ok. Of course the code being compiled would have to #include <sys/time.h>.

@pmacfarlane yes, the include file pasted above includes sys/time.h.    So maybe it is including the wrong sys/time.h?
